# How to subtract records from a table based on their existence in another

Tags: subquery, delete, ms-access-2010

I have an Access 2010 table `Assignment`

```
key Empl    Number
key Year    Number
key Week    Number
key Proj    Number
```

It assigns employees to zero or more projects for given work weeks,
thus, all four columns make up the composite key.
I have another table, `Import`, having identical structure, containing data to be used to update `Assignment` according to different options.

**Option 1**
Keep all existing assignments, add completely new imports, and ignore any imports that already exist.

I can manage that using a simple append query:

```
INSERT INTO Assignment 
SELECT *
FROM Import
```

So far, so good.

**Option 2**
As above, except where there's an employee-year-week match between assignment and import, replace the existing assignment with the import.

*One* approach to achieve that is to first delete all records with an employee-year-week match, then append the imports (as above).
The result should be to replace exact matches as-is, replace partial (employee-year-week) matches with new projects, and add completely new assignments.

I can isolate the matches via this query, called `Existing`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Import AS i INNER JOIN Assignment AS a 
ON a.Empl = i.Empl AND a.Year = i.Year AND a.Week = i.Week
```

How can I delete records from `Assignment` that are also in `Existing`?

I've tried variations upon this

```
DELETE 
FROM Assignment
WHERE IN (Existing)
```

all resulting in error messages.

By the way, it seems that, *if there were such an animal*, I could use a `MINUS` (or `DIFFERENCE`) query:

```
Assignment
MINUS
Existing
```

A minor variation on the approach would be to first delete the records with both an employee-year-week *match* and a project *mismatch*, then append the imports, as in Option 1. (Fewer deletions and additions, but same result.)

I can isolate those matches via this query, called `Existing_exp`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Import AS i INNER JOIN Assignment AS a 
ON a.Empl = i.Empl AND a.Year = i.Year AND a.Week = i.Week AND a.Proj <> i.Proj
```

but I'm still left with the task of how to delete records from `Assignment` that are in `Existing_exp`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the answer was hiding in plain sight:

```
DELETE a.*
FROM Import AS i INNER JOIN Assignment AS a 
ON a.Empl = i.Empl AND a.Year = i.Year AND a.Week = i.Week
```

or

```
DELETE a.*
FROM Import AS i INNER JOIN Assignment AS a 
ON a.Empl = i.Empl AND a.Year = i.Year AND a.Week = i.Week AND a.Proj <> i.Proj
```

depending on which is most appropriate.

I don't know how I failed to see it first time around!